# Excel Count unique values beetween 2 columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to count the number of times that first column have different values beetwen the 2 columns, like this example:

[image: example]

```
| 103942 | 820 |
| 103942 | 819 |
| 103953 | 819 |
| 103953 | 819 |
| 103953 | 819 |
| 103953 | 819 |
| 103953 | 820 |
| 103956 | 819 |
| 103956 | 819 |
| 103956 | 819 |
| 103956 | 819 |
| 103956 | 819 |
| 103956 | 820 |
| 103956 | 820 |
| 103956 | 819 |
| 103956 | 819 |
| 103956 | 818 |
| 103956 | 818 |
| 103956 | 819 |
| 103956 | 818 |
| 103956 | 819 |
| 103956 | 820 |
| 104157 | 818 |
| 104157 | 819 |
| 104157 | 820 |
| 104978 | 819 |
```

Is possible with only one formula?

Comment: ...or keep it simple and just make a pivot table with your data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try :

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `D3`

```
=LET(x,UNIQUE(A1:A26),
VSTACK({"","Uniques"},HSTACK(x,BYROW(x,LAMBDA(m,SUM((m=A1:A26)/COUNTIFS(A1:A26,A1:A26,B1:B26,B1:B26)))))))
```

Comment: I learned something new today. If this hasn't helped the OP it has helped me.

Comment: Glad to know that sir.

Answer (score 2):

The latest Excel version has a `Unique()` function, that can find unique entries or even unique combinations. Afterwards, you just need a simple `CountIfs()` to count them:

[image]

As you see, the `Unique()` function (just enter it in E2) creates the matrix of unique combinations.
The `CountIFS()` however needs to be dragged down from G2 to G9).